# kCFCalendarUnitQuarter not setting next fire date for the notification to fire notification quarterly

Tags: iphone, ios

I am facing an issue when setting up alarm using **local notification** in my application. In my application I want to set some alarms to fire weekly, some alarms daily and some alarms quarterly. Daily and weekly alarms set successfully but quarterly alarm not set successfully. I have tried below code to set the alarms:

```
    if(buttonIndex == 0) { // Daily
        notification.repeatInterval = NSDayCalendarUnit;
    }else if(buttonIndex == 1) { // Weekly
        notification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitWeek;
    }else if(buttonIndex == 2) { // Monthly
        notification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitMonth;
    }else if(buttonIndex == 3) { // Quertly
        notification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitQuarter;
    }else if(buttonIndex == 4) { // Annually
        notification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitYear;
    }

    notification.fireDate = fireDate;
    notification.userInfo = info;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

After writing this code I have debugged the application and logged the values in my debugger. It prints the value for next fire date except  `notification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitQuarter` option.

Can anyone help me in this issue for setting up alarm quarterly in the `iOS` application?

Answer (score 1):

Not solve your problem, but looks much better. Try to write good code for eyes.

```
       NSCalendarUnit unit;
    switch (buttonIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            unit = NSDayCalendarUnit;
            break;
        case 1:
            unit = kCFCalendarUnitWeek;
            break;
        case 2:
            unit = kCFCalendarUnitMonth;
            break;
        case 3:
            unit = kCFCalendarUnitQuarter;
            break;
        case 4:
            unit = kCFCalendarUnitYear;
            break;

        default:
        {
            NSLog(@"Ooops!");
            return;
        }
            break;
    }
    notification.fireDate = fireDate;
    notification.repeatInterval = unit;
    notification.userInfo = info;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```